# how to ignore hyphens in completion candidates using company-dabbrev backend?

Tags: company-mode, dabbrev

How can I modify `company-dabbrev` to behave like other `company-backends`, so I also receive words as completion candidates, that are connected with hyphens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've changed `company-dabbrev-char-regexp` from "\sw" to "\sw...[a-zA-Z0-9-]?+".

Now I can complete not only foobar, but also foo-bar.